# Why might a PDF in a kernel density plot be "spikey"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am plotting two kernel density plots where the Y-axis is the density, the X-axis is some attribute of the two data sets. Why might one data set look "spikey"? Is there some significant takeaway or inference that can be drawn about the data?

[image]

Comment: It looks to be either Pareto or exponential. Slopes right of the leftmost one are an experimental error due to the finite sample size. I'm not posting that as an answer yet because I'm unsure what you're asking about.

Comment: More context regarding your specific data is necessary to have a meaningful discussion.